# Scala: merge two arrays in one single structure

Tags: arrays, scala

I have two arrays:

```
val diceProbDist = new Array[Double](2 * DICE + 1)
```

and

```
val diceExpDist = new Array[Double](2 * DICE + 1)
```

and I want to merge in one single structure (some sort of tuple, maybe):

```
(0, 0.0, 0,0)(1, 0.0, 0.0)(2, 0.02778, 0.02878)...
```

where the first entry is the array index, the second entry is the first array value and the third entry is the second array value.

Is there some scala function to accomplish that (zip with map or something like that)?

thanks,
ML

Comment: `zipWithIndices' is your friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val diceProbDist = Array(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
val diceExpDist = Array(0.11, 0.22, 0.33)

diceProbDist
 .zip(diceExpDist)
 .zipWithIndex
 .map { case ((v1, v2), i) => (i, v1, v2) }

// result: Array((0,0.1,0.11), (1,0.2,0.22), (2,0.3,0.33))
```

Comment: Beautiful!! I was playing around with those concepts but with no success.

Comment: Is it fine that given solution does not compile?

Comment: Hmm, didn't notice this copy-paste error, thanks for correcting, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Simple `for` comprehension should also do the trick if you do not mind:

```
for {
  index <- 0 until math.min(diceExpDist.length, diceProbDist.length)
} yield (index, diceProbDist(index), diceExpDist(index))
```

Comment: This one is also cool. Coming from Java background, I can understand this for easily.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, similar to tkachuko's one without the for comprehension

```
val diceProbDist = List(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
val diceExpDist = List(0.11, 0.22, 0.33)

val range = 0 until math.min(diceExpDist.length, diceProbDist.length)
range.map { idx => (idx, c(idx), d(idx)) }

// result : res0: List[(Int, Int, Int)] = List((0,0,11), (1,1,12), (2,2,13), (3,3,14), (4,4,15), (5,5,16), (6,6,17), (7,7,18), (8,8,19), (9,9,20))
```